# discord.py join message embed not getting sent

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

I was just trying to code a welcome message for new members who join the server. I wanted to send an embed everytime a new member joins. However, the embed is not getting sent. Could someone please help me out?

This is my code:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    mention = member.mention
    guild = member.guild
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**New Member Joined!**", description=f"{mention} joined {guild}!", color = discord.Colour.purple())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar.url}")
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=Channel_ID)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are similar to permissions, you have to define Intents to get channels, members and some events etc. You have to define it before defining the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')`.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

Also, you have to activate Intents from your bot application in [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/).

If you want to get more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).